# No internet (Wi-Fi and Ethernet) on latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ethernet

It's been 12 hours and I'm still here trying to make internet work with Ubuntu so I hope you can help me somehow.. I'll start with my specs:

- Foxconn G33M
- Realtek RTL8110SC Ethernet Controller

I can tell the LAN cable is not the problem since I tested it with a different pc with Windows installaed and it works. I tried unplugging everything from the pc, keeping the power button pressed for 30 seconds, waiting 3-4 minutes with all the cables plugged off, I tried installing the latest version of the drivers, the previous version of these, I tried manually installing packages with errors since I don't know what dependencies they need. I tried using a wi-fi dongle, it can connect with my router but there is still no internet. I tried re-installing Ubuntu and same problems. I don't know what to do right now

This is a screenshot of my latest try https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw94s.png

And these are previous screenshots (before I decided to reinstall Ubuntu): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS2w0.png and [can't post more than 2 links..] https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f0pX.png

edit: this is the output -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/APHH9.png oh and I have no network-manager since a guy made me uninstall it for some reason

```
03:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet [10ec:8167] (rev 10)  
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet [105b:0cea]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: I edited my post!

Comment: @hiru is it solved? care to post an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try running

> sudo modprobe r8169

to activate the driver. Restart the machine and see if it works.

If it doesn't, you can download the driver from Realtek.

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=4&PFid=4&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8110SC(L)

Download the file **LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x**

There's a **Readme** file with instructions on how to install the driver. Read carefully, it shouldn't be that hard.